# How to replace line of a file with php

Tags: php

So, i need to make the file connect.php replace the variable $install = true(the true iw ant to be replaced) with false.

this is the connect.php file(with what i have tried and searched the internet for):

```
<?php
$db_servername = $_GET["servername"];
$db_username = $_GET["user"];
$db_password = $_GET["password"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{

    $myFile = "../config.php";
    $file = fopen("../config.php", "w+") or die("Error 404 file not found.");

    rewind($file);

    $contents = fread($file, filesize($myFile));
    $contents = str_replace('true','false', $contents, $count);
    fwrite($file, $contents);


    fclose($file);  

} 
?>
```

And this is the config.php file, file where i wanted $install's var info to be replaced from true to false:

```
<?php
include("../connect.php");

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password);


// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$install = true;

?>
```

Please don't answer with something else than i am asking. like if you see a mistake in my code. just forget you saw it, i'll just solve it. I REALLY NEED the replacement method.

Comment: like, if you know how, wordpress toggles an installation mode, so that the index will redirect you to the installer, not to the actual index(where the site is)

Comment: What is the question? What does your code do? What isn't working?

Comment: also, i realised i can't include the connect file into the config file, cause when i will include the config file into other pages, to connect to db and get the upcoming(gonna put more) variables, and it will keep replacing the text line or word, even if it can't do it, it's not normal, so i'll put the next variables in place of the include thing, and make the connect file replace the variables desc to the actual db host, user and password.                                            $db_servername = $_GET["servername"];
$db_username = $_GET["user"];
$db_password = $_GET["password"];

Comment: Use a sort of lock file and check it's existence. If it's not there, install, if it is, it's already installed. There are many other ways that don't involve files at all, but it's a simple solution.

Comment: can you please tell me that solution that doesn't include files, because i am already tired of this. i am staying and trying to solve this problem for like 2 days... :(

Comment: Well, the lock file will remove your need to manipulate PHP files, which imo is the main thing, as for other options, I don't know as it's your project, so only you can say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change program code on runtime.

Instead, store your information in a text file like

```
file_put_contents('install-info.txt', '1');
```

and read it like that:

```
if (file_get_contents('install-info.txt') === '1') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: OMG! TY FOR THE FILE_GET CONTENT IDEA. i tought about using the file_get_content way and searched internet for that and done it wiht this code

Comment: $str = file_get_contents('../config.php');
 $str = str_replace("true", "false",$str);
 file_put_contents('../config.php', $str);